# How to resolve SOQL SOSL Injection security error

Tags: soql, sosl, security-review

I am fairly new to salesforce. I am getting the soql sosl injection error in the below method while doing query. How to resolve this error?

```
 public static Days_Unavailable__c getAvlRecordById(String avlId){
            String query = QUERY_PART1 + ' where Id = \'' + avlId + '\' and Event_Status__c!=NULL ';
            
            selector.checkRead(QUERY_PART1_FIELDS);
            List<Days_Unavailable__c> avlList = Database.query(query);
            
            if(avlList != null && avlList.size() > 0 ){
                return avlList.get(0);
            }else{
                return null;    
            }
            
        }
```

I set the 'QUERY_PART1' and 'QUERY_PART1_FIELDS'  as:

```
    final static String QUERY_PART1 = 'select Id, Weekly_Recurrence__c, Recurrence_Weekdays__c, Recurrence_End_Date__c, Start_Date__c, Candidate_Management__r.name, Candidate_Management__r.Placement__r.name, Candidate_Management__r.Placement__r.Company__r.name,End_Date__c, Event_Status__c, EventReason__c, Contact__c from Days_Unavailable__c';
    final static String QUERY_PART1_FIELDS = 'Id, Start_Date__c, Candidate_Management__r.name, Candidate_Management__r.Placement__r.name, Candidate_Management__r.Placement__r.Company__r.name,End_Date__c, Event_Status__c, EventReason__c, Contact__c';
```

Comment: Can you try this while executing query.  `List<Days_Unavailable__c> avlList = Database.query(String.escapeSingleQuotes(query));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two options:

- Use a merge variable. Simple, compact, easy to read.

  ```
  String query = QUERY_PART1 + ' where Id = :avlId and Event_Status__c!=NULL ';
  ```
- Escape the input.

  ```
  String query = QUERY_PART1 + ' where Id = \'' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(avlId) +
      '\' and Event_Status__c!=NULL ';
  ```

I also recommend ***very strongly*** you use complete words in all your variable names. Abbreviations are horrendous for readability.